# Having trouble with SSIS connections to a remote database using wrong database login

Tags: database, ssis, remote-access

We have SSIS setup with packages and connection string that are supposed to access remote databases but when I run the packages I get logins that match the User who is the SQL Server logged in User, not the Usernames set up in the connection strings.

Is this just how SSIS works, or is there a way to call a package with an existing Connection String to make the proper call to a remote database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this was the fact that in the original SQL Connection strings within the Catalog the Integrated Security=SSPI was set; this pretty much guaranteed that I would always be getting connections as the logged in User.  Regardless of what User ID or Password was in the connection string, that was ignored.  Removing the Integrated Security property/value gets around this issue, so long as they are set up in the SSIS Catalog with the right values, they will be used and not the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, this may not be the best fit for you but...

You can store the connection string in a variable, then using an expression on the connection manager to set the connection string to the variable content.

[image]

Comment: I have the remote user configured in the connection string already,  does this have some extra permission that assures it's used?

Comment: Depending on the encryption level of the package, SSIS will strip the password from the connection definition.  I use this to reliably force SSIS to use the connection exactly as defined.

Comment: It's not the password that is the problem I am encountering, as much as the Username, it's not using the one in the connection string.  Will SSIS try and substitute another User for that if the encryption level is not set?

Comment: I doubt it, but SSIS sometimes does things I don't expect.